# Are string parameters usually automatically escaped in web services?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I found out today that a simple `%` inside a string parameter passed from the client to the server results in a `Bad Request 400`.

Since I have basic knowledge with Web services I don't know if this is a normal behavior.  Did I miss something (is it my responsability to escape strings?) or should I look somewhere else?

Client code :

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "push", action = "urn:Push")
public boolean push(String msg);
```

Server code :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "push", namespace = "http://ws.something.com/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "push", namespace = "http://ws.something.com/", propOrder = {"arg0"})
public class Push {

    @XmlElement(name = "arg0")
    private java.lang.String arg0;

    public java.lang.String getArg0() {
        return this.arg0;
    }

    public void setArg0(java.lang.String newArg0)  {
        this.arg0 = newArg0;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

This client/server pair works fine locally on our development host server even with a `%` inside the string parameter.  However it does result in `Bad Request 400` on another host server.  So it might be related to the server host environment.  If so, I would like to have a hint on what might cause this.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the default charset is different in your environments. Try this sample.

```
    String test = new String("%");
    System.out.println(test);
    byte[] byteArray = test.getBytes("UTF-16");
    test = new String(byteArray);
    System.out.println(test);
```

It's pretty rudimentary, but you will get an idea about how character encoding impacts the result.

Check this for additional details.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: If it is an encoding issue why are all the other characters transferred correctly?

Comment: Depends on the charset. If it falls in the supported charset then it will come out properly. It's highly unlikely you will ever face issues with English alphabets. Special characters or other language characters will give weird result if the charset is wrong. I think you can get the default charset from System. You can google that. I will check and respond if I get time to check.

Comment: I use french characters and they are all transferred correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It is the programmers responsibility to escape strings.   Java provides a class to do the encoding and decoding.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html  and its complement :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
...
public java.lang.String getArg0() {
    return URLEncoder.encode(this.arg0);
}
```